# Why python docstring is interpreted differently from comment

Tags: python, python-2.7, docstring

Let's say, I've got a function like this:

```
def myFunc():
    # useful function to calculate stuff
```

This will produce an indentation error, unless I add `pass`:

```
def myFunc():
    # useful function to calculate stuff
    pass
```

However, if I replace a comment with docstring, no `pass` is necessary:

```
def myFunc():
    """useful function to calculate stuff"""
```

This seems like an odd feature as neither of these are used in the program, as far as I know. So, why does it behave like this?

Comment: because, not being a comment, it is interpreted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A docstring *isn't* just a comment.  It actually has meaning to the interpreter.  In the case with a docstring, you could do `myFunc.__doc__` and actually get your docstring back (In the other case with a `pass`, the result `myFunc.__doc__` would be `None`).

In other words, you are actually adding some code to the function body to modify it's behavior (in some circumstances), so no `pass` is necessary.

Answer (score 7):

A comment is outright ignored by the interpreter, so omitting a block after an indent is a syntax error. However, a docstring is a real Python object--at its most basic, a literal `str`. A lone expression is a valid block of code:

```
'This is a string. It is a valid (though pretty useless) line of Python code.'
```

In the case of docstrings in particular, there's also some additional functionality going on, such as being used to set the `__doc__` attribute.

```
>>> def myFunc():
...     '''MyDocString'''
...
>>> print(myFunc.__doc__)
MyDocString
```

Note that this also works for classes:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     '''MyClassDocString'''
...
>>> print(MyClass.__doc__)
MyClassDocString
```

Comment: Oh, wow, I had no idea that a string is an actual valid python statement!